# Which command-line tool can be used to make video screenshots from a videofile?

Tags: video, command-line, screenshot, capture

I have a video file and want to make a screenshot series like this one

[image]

Which program can be used for that? Is there any command-line tool?

Answer (score 2):

Your example was done in [Media Player Classic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/). While playing the video simply go to **File -> Save Thumbnails**.

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) can also do this.

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg img%d.jpg
```

this will make a series of images named img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc.

Comment: Damn, you edited your answer ;)

Comment: Yeah I never checked his example his explanation sounded good enough. Then I checked it and saw **Media Player Classic** across it in giant letters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux then [Video Contact Sheet *NIX](http://p.outlyer.net/vcs/) is an excellent wrapper around a number of utilities to automate making thumbnail sheets with a decent set of options for customising the output. If you are using Windows/Max/BSD then you may have less luck with it, though the creator states that better support for other OSs is planned in later versions.

Comment: +1 for a tool that just gets the job done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a command-line tool written in Python called [vcsi](https://github.com/amietn/vcsi) which can be used like this:

```
vcsi video.mkv -o output.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `montage` command merge pictures,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853334/glueing-tile-images-together-using-imagemagicks-montage-command

and there is the useage:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. When answering questions it is customary to include the answer from sites and refer them, meaning that you describe the procedure yourself and add references to those methods. The reason for this is in case the the sites you are refering to goes down, the explanation will still be available here at superuser.